# Custom Post Type Pagination for Bones Theme

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination to my custom post type and I am using the bones theme framework as well as their function they provide for pagination. 
Here is my code

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_type',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
        $wp_query->the_post();?>

        //DO STUFF HERE

    endwhile;
    if ( function_exists( 'bones_page_navi' ) ) {
        bones_page_navi(); 
    } else { 
        next_posts_link( __( '&laquo; Older Entries', 'bonestheme' ));
        previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer Entries &raquo;', 'bonestheme' ));
    }
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Custom Post Type, by default, has an archive so you should really be using that, in which pagination will work.

If your post type is called 'products' then your archive will be at:

http://www.yoursite.com/products/

You then don't need to do the WP_Query as the query has already been executed by WordPress.

If you need to change any arguments such as post_per_page you should use the `pre_get_posts()` hook.

WP_Query is usually just used for running secondary queries on a page, where in this case it looks like you can use the main query.